# How to match Oracle reported xml parsing error in C#

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

In dotnetcore 3.1,  C#, I am writing an xml string to an oracle OracleDbType.XmlType field using a adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() call.

This is the part of the string causing the trouble:

```
 <mothersname>Potter&#128077;</mothersname>
```

You can see it has an emoji in it.. the &#128077 bit...

Oracke throws an exception when I attempt the insert:

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
In line 11 of orastream:
LPX-00217: invalid character 128077 (U+1F44D)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution
```

But when I try to check the xml string before attempting to write it to the db using this func:

```
  public static bool ContainsIllegalCharacters(string toCheck)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(toCheck);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Xml.XmlException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
}
```

I don't get any indication that the string is invalid .
So, it appears that Oracle is using a different parser?
Would that be right?
Or is it using a particular XSD maybe?

Is there any way to get the same version of parsing working?

**I'd like to reject the request as having invalid xml before attempting to write it to the db.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or a specific encoding / code page so that your XML appears to contain an illegal character. You should check your Oracle configuration to get more information.

Comment: The digits are suppose to be a 4 digit unicode number.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true